# How to Create Link to Repository File in Wiki

Tags: tfs

Using: latest version of Azure on premises DevOps
Goal: on a wiki page link to a specific object in one of the GIT repositories within the same project (e.g., a word document).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to use the following format in Wiki:

```
URL: [text to display](RepoURL)
```

For example:

```
[link](https://{ServerName}/{CollectionName}/_git/{ProjectName}?path=%2FREADME.md)
```

This format applies to all repos.

If the target file is under the repo of the wiki, you can use the file path to set the link. The method here has **limitations**.

```
Absolute path in Git: [text to display](/folder/target.md)
```

For example:

Files

[image]

link

```
[link](/aspnet/Views/Shared/1.md)
```

In this case, the link file needs to be a text that can be displayed on the wiki(e.g. .md file).

**Note:** If the file is in another repo, the absolute path cannot be used.

Here is a doc about [Wiki MarkDown.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops-2020#links)

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin! This makes total sense (now I feel dumb).